# How can I decompose this VAR equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, vector-auto-regression

I have this VAR equation

$\begin{pmatrix}
s_t\\
f_t
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\begin{pmatrix}
1-0.4L & 0.3L\\
-0.6L & 1-0.1L
\end{pmatrix}}{(1-0.1L)(1-0.4L)+0.18L^2} \begin{pmatrix}
0.5\\0.7\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}ε_t\\
η_t\end{pmatrix}  $

This has been written as:
$s_t =0.51+0.5s_{t1}-0.22s_{t-2}+ε_t-0.4ε_{t-1}+0.3η_{t-1}$
And
$f_t=0.33+0.5f_{t1}-0.22f_{t-2}+η_t-0.6ε_{t-1}+0.1η_{t-1}$

I have absolutely no idea how the fraction with the two matrices is solved and transformed into two equations, could someone explain how this is done ? I only know how to compute the inverse of a matrix when it involves actual numbers only and in this case I’m Absolutely clueless

I tried to bring the denominator to the left but then I realised the matrix is then left on its own and I’m not sure how to proceed after that step

Thanks :)

Comment: The denominator is a scalar value. But why is $L$ missing from the final form?

Comment: Still , I’m clueless how to approach it, L basically means lagged value of st and ft. L^2 means it’s ft-2 or st-2

Comment: Can you provide some more context and details. Like what is $s_{t1}$, $s_{t-2}$ etc.

Comment: I’m not sure , s and f are two different variables , but I just wanted to find out how to solve this fraction of matrices

Comment: It is not a fraction of matrices. It is scalar value multiplied with a matrix. $$ \frac{ [\cdot ]}{d} = \frac{1}{d} [\cdot ] $$

Comment: Well whatever it is I don’t know how to solve it, if I knew I wouldn’t be asking this question:/

Comment: You multiply _every element_ of the matrix with the scalar $$ f\,\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}f & 2f\\
3f & 4f
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I’ve tried that already but I don’t know how to decompose this matrix , and how to get to this final result of these two equations for f and s, by taking the denominator to the left it still doesn’t really solve the equation because the matrix is left on its own and it can’t be decomposed I suppose

Comment: More information is needed to go beyond the scalar-matrix operation.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all the information I have  it should be possible though